# What is a "log-bilinear regression model?"

Tags: regression, neural-networks

I was reading the original paper for the GloVe model and was confused on what the authors meant by "global log-bilinear regression model."

I've read this question ([log-linear vs. log-bilinear](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/157136/log-linear-vs-log-bilinear)) that's on this community as well, but is it different from what a log-bilinear regression model is?

I'm finding myself confused because the results that I found for a log-bilinear model seem different compared to the model that the authors propose.